# Is it possible to dynamically update a SWT StyledText widget based on model changes?

Tags: java, swt, listener, styledtext

I'm working on the SWT `StyledText` widget. I tried the `setStyleRanges()` approach and the `LineStyleListener` approach by providing text.

Now I'm wondering if there could be a possibility to use `StyledText` not with a String as input  but with custom objects and then make this `Styledtext` able to automatically update when one of  the custom objects changes.

For example, I would have a Content class which would have a text property and a boolean property (`isBold`). I would set a list of Content objects as input for the `StyledText` and when one of them has its `isBold` property set to true, the `StyledText` would be refreshed and the text font would be set to bold.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think so. You can use a `TextViewer` and add change listeners on its document to make your job easier so that you only apply style ranges to the newly added modifications. But you will need to set the style ranges yourself.

```java
TextViewer viewer = new TextViewer();
viewer.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new IDocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void documentChanged(final DocumentEvent event) {
        // use event.fText, event.fOffset etc to apply changes to document
        ...
    }
});
```